# Public folder emails not being delivered

Tags: exchange-2003, exchange-2010, public-folders, exchange-migration

We have just introduced an Exchange 2010 installation into our existing Exchange 2003 (all standard) environment.  We make a lot of use of our Public Folders in 2003, so I am wanting to make a small PF tree in the 2010 system to test some applications against.

I have created a few public folders in the 2010 public folder management tool, and mail enabled them, gotten email addresses, etc.  However, mail will not be delivered, it queues on my existing 2003 Exchange server's 'Local Delivery' queue, and eventually times out and bounces.

I guess the Exchange 'system' including the new 2010 server thinks that all public folder email must need to be delivered to the old 2003 server.

Is it possible for me to have two public folder databases that each receive mail?  If so, is there something I am missing to enable this?

Thanks

-R

Answer (score 0):

If you run Get-RoutingGroupConnector on the Exchange 2010 server do you see two RGCs connecting the legacy RG to the Exchange 2010 RG?

Can emails between mailboxes on Exchange 2003 and Exchange 2010 deliver successfully?

Do the NDRs you receive back include a MapiExceptionNotAuthorized error?  If so [check this out](http://exchangeserverpro.com/causes-of-mapiexceptionnotauthorized-error-sending-to-public-folders).